# Displaying images from a csv with d3

Tags: javascript, html, image, d3.js

I am very new to javascript, d3, and polymer project.

I have a csv file with information about images, I've parsed the file and created an array that only contains the Image URL.
Now I want to display those images on my polymer project. However, when I try to utilize the array nothing happens.

```
d3.csv("./images2.csv",function (data) {
 var URL = data.map(function(d) {return d.imageUrl});
 var urlArray = [];
 urlArray.push(URL);

 //display 1st image?
 document.write('<img src=" + urlArray[0] + "/>');
});
```

Im not sure if I have the wrong syntax or am approaching this in the wrong way but I havent been able to find anything that has been useful. Any help or advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Final code: document.write('<img src="' + URL[0] + '"/>');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This won't work as you've tried as you're putting an array into an array (saying this without seeing your csv file) then trying to call the outer which returns an array

Assuming `URL` is an array of URLs, these lines are pointless and you can remove them: `var urlArray = []; urlArray.push(URL);`

Then try `document.write('<img src=" + URL[0] + "/>');`

Full code:

```
d3.csv("./images2.csv",function (data) {
 var URL = data.map(function(d) {return d.imageUrl});
 //display 1st image?
 document.write('<img src=" + URL[0] + "/>');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using Polymer another approach to display all images could be to loop over your array using the dom-repeat that ships with Polymers template element. Depending on your Polymer version you might have to adjust it a bit but thats how I used to do it.

**The Property:**

```
iframeLinks: {
  type: Array,
  value: function(){
    return []
  }
},
```

**The function:**

```
d3.csv("./images2.csv",function (data) {
  this.urlArray = data.map(function(d) {return d.imageUrl});
}.bind(this));
```

**The HTML:**

```
<template is="dom-repeat" items="{{urlArray}}">
  <img src$="[[item]]"></img>
</template>
```